# Assets from the asset browser copy the geometry nodes modifier, is there a way to make them a single user copy?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, asset-browser

I have mesh assets in asset browser.

Each time I drag them into the scene, the geometry nodes modifier to the mesh also gets copied. I have to click the number (3) to make them a single user copy.

[image]

I want the modifier to be a single use copy when I add an asset to the scene, is this possible?

I know there is a setting in preferences that changes the import method from append(reuse data) to append, but this doesn't work for modifiers.

[image]

Comment: I know that when adding a nodegroup asset (same type as modifier) into geometry node as an asset and then I add another one it will use the one I already have in the file and not duplicate, this could actually get annoying when I change the inside of the node and don't make have a new name or user the new node will be the same as the one I changed (only in that file though). It could be different if the modifier is on an object (and not as a modifier) like as in your case.